# How to combine a list of choices to determine which select statement

Tags: php, sql, variables, switch-statement

I have a mysql db and am using php 5.2

What I am trying to do is offer a list of options for a person to select (only 1).
The chosen option will cause a select, update, or delete statement to be ran.

The results of the statement do not need to be shown, although, showing the old and
then the new would be nice (no problems with that part tho'.).

Pseudo-Code:

```
Assign $choice = 0
Check the value of $choice  //  This way, if it = 100, we do a break
Select a Choice:<br>
  1.  Adjust Status Value (+60) // $choice = 1<br>
  2.  Show all Ships <br> // $choice = 2
  3.  Show Ships in Port <br> // $choice = 3
  ...  
  0.  $choice="100"  // if the value =100, quit this part
```

Use either case (switch) or if/else statements to run the users choice1

```
If the choice is 1, then run the "Select" statement with the variable of $sql1
    --  "SELECT ....
If the choice is 2, then run the "Select" statement with the variable of $sql2
    --- SELECT * FROM Ships
If the choice is 3, then run the "Select" statement with the variable of $sql3  <br>
    ....
If the choice is 0, then we are done.
```

I figured the (3) statements would be assigned in php as:

```
$sql1="...".
$sql2="SELECT * FROM Ships"
$sql3="SELECT * FROM Ships WHERE nPort="1"
```

My idea was to use the switch statement, but got lost on it. :(

I would like the options to be available over and over again, until a variable ($choice)
is selected.  In which case, this particular page is done and goes back to the "Main Menu"?

The coding and display, if I use it, I can do.  Just not sure how to write the way to select
which one I want.  It is possible that I would run all of the queries, and other times, only
one, so that is why I would like the choice.  An area I get confused in is the proper forms
to use such as -- ' ' " " and ...??

Not sure the # of options I will end up with, but it will be more than 5 but less than 20 / page.  So if I get the system down for 2-3 choices, I can replicate it for as many as I may need.  And, as always, if a better way exists, I am willing to try it.

Thanks again...

Larry

Answer (score 0):

[Switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) is a nice way to go.  `if-then` is fine, too, depending on the needs.

For your example, you'd be talking about something like so:

```
switch($choice) {
    case 1:
        $sql = $sql1="...".
        break;
    case 2:
        $sql2="SELECT * FROM Ships"
        break;
    case 3:
        $sql3="SELECT * FROM Ships WHERE nPort="1"
        break;
    default:
        // Do some default behavior - as you mentioned
}
```

If you'd like it to be re-usable, you could put it into a function:

```
function getSQL($choice) {

    switch($choice) {
        case 1:
            $sql = $sql1="...".
            break;
        case 2:
            $sql="SELECT * FROM Ships"
            break;
        case 3:
            $sql="SELECT * FROM Ships WHERE nPort="1"
            break;
        default:
            // Do some default behavior - as you mentioned
    }
    return $sql;
}
```

Then, you could just call it like so:

```
$mysql = getSQL($choice);
```