# Run select statement from a php menu

Tags: php, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to combine a list of choices to determine which select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388736/how-to-combine-a-list-of-choices-to-determine-which-select-statement)

This was asked before -- confusingly by me.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to find my post to modify it. :(

So.  Simple version.

1. Create a menu where the choice will run a mysql select statement.
   -- Statement does not have to be displayed.

Example Menu Options:
1.  Update_Inventory
2.  Conduct_Training
3.  Conduct_Repairs

When I select 1-3, it should run the SELECT, UPDATE, or ... statement.
I can write the sql statements, just don't know how to link a menu choice
with the statement.

Comment: If you're selecting something, you should display it. I believe you mean a 'Query'. (Just to get the terminology out of the way). Moving on...have you considered using the value of the combobox or whatever means you use for deciding what to do in a switch/case to decide on the actual query? A little example of what you're trying to do would be good.

Comment: @larry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388736/how-to-combine-a-list-of-choices-to-determine-which-select-statement   check your profile (click your name at the top of the page). it'll show you all of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you're talking about Ajax?

Take each menu option as a unique action. You've already named them:

```
$menu = array('Update_Inventory', 'Conduct_Training', 'Conduct_Repairs');
```

Loop through menu array and apply onclick event handler to each link that you print out:

```
<?php foreach($menu as $menuItem): ?>
    <a href="#" onclick="run_action('<?php echo $menuItem; ?>')">
        <?php echo $menuItem; ?>
    </a>
    <br />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Your JS function for handling onclick events:

```
function run_action(action){
     //perform an ajax request to PHP script that runs whatever query
     //corresponds to the action that has been received.
}
```

Comment: this implies that a switch / conditional statement has to be in the "run_action" method, right?

Comment: +1 I like this implementation method :) SUGGESTION though, wouldn't it be better / more efficient to have ID's in the array? $menu = array(1=> 'Update_Inventory', 2=> 'Conduct_Training' ...); thus making the conditional statement in the function integer based rather than string based limiting the potentials for mistakes? =)

Answer (score 0):

Either a) set the menu items to normal anchor tag links that point to a PHP file.  That file runs the MySQL query.   Or b) use Ajax to hit that same PHP file.